# How can I determine if a file is empty?

Tags: c, file-io

How do I determine if a file is empty? The file is opened by a C program running on the Windows platform. I want to open a file in append mode, and, if empty, first print a header to it.

```
// Open CSV & write header
report_csv = fopen("SNR.csv", "a+");
if (!report_csv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open CSV output file...");
    return -1;
}
if (!ftell(report_csv)) {
    fprintf(report_csv, "Column A;Column B;Column C\n");
}
// ... print data to file
fclose(report_csv);
```

I was expecting `ftell` to return the current file size if the file was not empty, which happens because the code above is looped.

However, `ftell` always returns `0` and the header is printed multiple times.

I know I could `fopen` it with `r` and use `fseek`/`ftell`/`fclose` and then `fopen` it again with `a+`, but I think it's possible to do this without opening and closing the file multiple times.

Comment: File I/O operations differ between operating systems, so... what is the OS you're working with?

Comment: `Unable to open CSV output file...` is the canonical example of a *bad* error message.  Include the actual file name, and the reason for the error (`man perror` and `man strerror`).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: for the sake of clarity, the code has been striped out of unnecessary information. The actual code contains a more explicit error message (including file path) and an actual return code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, when `fopen`ing a file in append mode, the file pointer is initially at the begining of the file. It moves to the end of it as soon as you write something or use `fseek`.

I just needed to add `fseek(report_csv, 0, SEEK_END);` before my `if (!ftell(report_csv))`.

**Let's check this.**
*Code*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *test;
    size_t size;
    char buf[100];

    /* Truncate file */
    test = fopen("test", "w");
    if (!test) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file `test`!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Write something */
    fprintf(test, "Something. ");
    fclose(test);

    /* Open in append */
    test = fopen("test", "a+");
    if (!test) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open `test` in append mode!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Try to get the file size */
    size = ftell(test);
    printf("File pointer is: %d\n", size);
    fseek(test, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(test);
    printf("After `fseek(test, 0, SEEK_END)`, the file pointer is: %d\n", size);

    /* Append */
    fprintf(test, "And that. ");
    fclose(test);

    /* Same without fseek */
    test = fopen("test", "a+");
    if (!test) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open `test` in append mode!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(test, "Hello! ");
    size = ftell(test);
    printf("File size is now: %d\n", size);
    fclose(test);

    /* Try to read */
    test = fopen("test", "r");
    if (!test) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open `test` for reading!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File contents:\n\t");
    while (test && !feof(test)) {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), test);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    /* Cleanup & exit */
    fclose(test);
    printf("\n\nExiting.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

*Output*:

```
File pointer is: 0
After `fseek(test, 0, SEEK_END)`, the file pointer is: 11
File size is now: 28
File contents:
        Something. And that. Hello!

Exiting.
```

Answer (score 2):

When opening a file with `fopen` with the `a+` mode, all writing operations will be performed at the end of the file. You can reposition the internal pointer to anywhere in the file for reading, but writing operations will move it back to the end of file. The initial pointer position for reading is at the beginning of the file.

So you need to call an `fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END)` on your `FILE` pointer.

Comment: Yep that's right! I figured this just ten mins ago. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did not refresh the page... sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `_stat()` and get the value `st_size` into `struct _stat` (you dont need open the file).
Declared in `sys/types.h` followed by `sys/stat.h`
I don´t know Windows programming, but it can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx